# How to determine if a Fragment was opened first time?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose i have a main fragment that handles a game, i put the game board into the fragment build arguments using setArguments, and i need to init the game board layout only the first time the game was shown to the user, any other time, such as when he gets back to the app after pressing home key or having a phone call, I need not to change the board. I can easily do that by adding some boolean to the arguments bundle setting it to true in the first time and check it before initing the layout, but I was wondering if there is another way using fragments lifecycle callbacks?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yeah that is obvious, but i wanted to know if there is a way to distinguish between first creation and other creations using the callbacks like there is for an activity (savedState==null)

Comment: ... use SharedPreferences? so you can persist the boolean state.

Answer (score 0):

Try setRetainInstance(true) in onPause() and getRetainInstance() in onResume() of the Parent Activity as below:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment")
        .setRetainInstance(true);


getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment")
        .getRetainInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think this will help

First set the SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();

Editor editor.putBoolean(KEY, Val);
editor.commit();
```

To get the value:

```
pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
```

Comment: I think this answers the question, I would only add that in Application's onCreate I would clear this flag, if this is something that needs to be shown every time user opens an app for the first time (ie. after reboot or app being killed)

Comment: i have it in my app in the Applications onCreate too :D

Answer (score -1):

You could check in this way:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           if(savedInstanceState == null){
               //firstTime
           }
     }
```